# Pulling data from database in CodeIgniter ( or any MVC platform)?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, model-view-controller, codeigniter

I have this in Model:

```
public function index_loop() { 
        $post_user = $this->db->query("SELECT posts.post_title, posts.post_content, posts.post_date, users.username FROM posts LEFT JOIN users ON posts.user_id = users.user_id ORDER BY posts.post_ID DESC");
        //$categories = $this->db->query("SELECT categories.cat_name, categories.cat_id FROM  
        //$comments = $this->db->query("SELECT COUNT(comment_id) FROM comments WHERE
        return $post_user->result_array();
    }
```

What I need is to show categories for each post and comments (although I guess if I figure out categories passing than comments are the same way)

in View file:

```
 <?php foreach($posts as $zz) { ?>
         <div class="article">
           <h2><?php echo $zz['post_title']; ?></h2>
           <p>Posted by <a href=""><?php echo $zz['username']; ?></a> | Filed under <a href="#">templates</a>, <a href=>internet</a></p>
            <p><?php echo $zz['post_content']; ?></p>
           <p><a href=>Read more</a> | <a href=>Comments (5)</a> | <?php echo $zz['post_date']; ?></p>
        </div> <?php } ?>
```

So, if I want to loop categories on each blog I need that blogs ID, how do I get it if I make all queries from Model? 
The same for comments

Is it good that I make one big complicated DB query ( which is hard but I can do it) or I can do 2 or 3 separate smaller queries?

Comment: and I have separate table for categories where categories_id and posts_id are toghether, so only relation_id, cat_id, post_id in Relationship table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Codeigniter allows you to return database results as objects (model objects, for example), which makes data much easier to work with.  You can issue your initial query to the `Posts` table, include the `posts.id` field in your result set, and pass the name of your `Post_model` class to the `$db->query->result()` function to tell codeigniter that you'd like your result(s) returned as instances of the `Post_model` class.

You can then define methods on the `Post_model` class to `GetCategories` by `post_id` and `GetComments` by `post_id`, and then call these methods to populate your `$categories` and `$comments` collections for each `Post_model` returned from your query.

Here's an example, i hope it helps:

```
    public class Post_model extends CI_Model
    {

        // All the properties in the Posts table, as well as a couple variables to hold the categories and comments for this Post:
        public $id;
        public $post_title;
        public $post_content;
        public $post_date;
        public $username;        
        public $categories;
        public $comments;

        public function index_loop() 
        { 
                return $this->GetAllPosts();
        }

        // function to get all posts from the database, including comments and categories.
        // returns an array of Post_model objects
        public function GetAllPosts()
        {
                // define an empty array to hold the results of you query.
                $all_posts = array();

                // define your sql query. NOTE the POSTS.ID field has been added to the field list
                $sql = "SELECT posts.id, 
                               posts.post_title, 
                               posts.post_content, 
                               posts.post_date,
                               users.username
                        FROM posts LEFT JOIN users ON posts.user_id = users.user_id
                        ORDER BY posts.post_id DESC";

                // issue the query
                $query = $this->db->query($sql);

                // loop through the query results, passing a string to result() which represents a class to instantiate 
                //for each result object (note: this class must be loaded)

                foreach($query->result("Post_model") as $post)
                {
                        $post->categories = $this->GetPostCategories($post->id);
                        $post->comments = $this->GetPostComments($post->id);
                        $all_posts[] = $post;
                }

                return $all_posts;
        }

        // function to return categories for a given post_id.
        // returns an array of Category_model objects.
        public function GetPostCategories($post_id)
        {
                $sql = "SELECT category.id, ... WHERE post_id = ?";
                $query = $this->db->query($sql, array($post_id));
                $categories = array();
                foreach($query->result("Category_model") as $category)
                {
                        $categories[] = $category;
                }
                return $categories;
        }

        // function to return comments for a given post_id. 
        //returns an array of Comment_model objects
        public function GetPostComments($post_id)
        {
                $sql = "SELECT comment.id, ... WHERE post_id = ?";
                $query = $this->db->query($sql, array($post_id));
                $comments = array();
                foreach($query->result("Comment_model") as $comment)
                {
                        $comments[] = $comment;
                }
                return $comments;
        }    
}
```

Then, in your view, you can access your $posts array as Post_model objects rather than as result_arrays:

```
<?php foreach($posts as $zz) { ?>
         <div class="article">
           <h2><?php echo $zz->post_title; ?></h2>
           <p>Posted by <a href=""><?php echo $zz->username; ?></a> | 

              Filed under 
               <?php foreach($zz->categories as $category) {
                        echo '<a href="#">{$category->name}</a>, ';
                     }
               ?>
           </p>
           <p><?php echo $zz->post_content; ?></p>
           <p><a href=>Read more</a> | <a href=>Comments (5)</a> | <?php echo $zz->post_date; ?></p>
        </div> <?php } ?>
```

As for the question of efficiency, it's going to depend on a lot of factors (is the database located on the same machine as the web server? how many posts are there? etc).  A single large query will typically perform quicker than several smaller ones, but it will require profiling to really determine whether the performance gains are worth seeking.  I always prefer to try and write readable/understandable code rather than optimize at the expense of adding complexity.

Comment: thank you very much for understanding my question, this is what I need, but I didn't know it's this complicated but I think I can handle it just I need a bit more efforts :) I will get back to you just for one more little question, I hope you don't mind

Comment: you passed "Post_model" to result $query->result in foreach loop, in documentation it says "represents a class to instantiate for each result object (note: this class must be loaded)" like you put in comments,  so what would $query->result("Post_model") return, if it refers to this current class Post_model, does it access all methods in this class?

Comment: and also $query->result("Category_model") and Comments_model, I need to make those in separate file?

Comment: $query->result("Post_model") would instantiate one instance of Post_model for the current row of data, and set instance variables with the names of the fields returned from the query.  Category_model and Comment_model should each be defined in their own files, just like the Post_model class.

Answer (score 0):

You can do 1 thing.

make different category table and comments table.

category_id will be linked with category_id column in post table.

In comment table, create column post_id which will be linked with post_id in post table.

then you can retrieve all the information at once by this extended query.

```
$post_user = $this->db->query("SELECT posts.post_title, posts.post_content, posts.post_date, users.username FROM posts LEFT JOIN users ON posts.user_id = users.user_id LEFT JOIN category ON category.category_id = post.category_id ORDER BY posts.post_ID DESC");
```

here you got the category.

For comment, i am not sure how you want the output as. one way is as Yan said. If you can be more specific, i can advice some simpler approach.